# Sending variables in URLs in PHP with echo

Tags: php, mysql, url, variables

I can't really find good guidelines through Google searches of the proper way to escape variables in URLs. Basically I am printing out a bunch of results from a MySQL query in a table, and I want one of the entries in each row to be a link to that result's page. I think this is easy, that I'm just missing a apostrophe or backslash somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Here's the line that's causing the error:

```
echo "<a href = \"movies.php/?movie_id='$row['movie_id']'\"> Who Owns It? </a> ";
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING
```

How do I fix this error?

In addition, what are some general guidelines for working with echo and variables in URLs?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses. I tested all of the answers below and they all work (for those viewing this in the future). It seems to be mostly a matter of preference/readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<a href = \"movies.php/?movie_id='$row['movie_id']'\"> Who Owns It? </a> ";
```

There are two things here that should be changed.  For one thing there shouldn't be a / after movies.php.  The second is that there aren't any apostrophies around url variables.  It should be movie_id=$row['movie_id'].  Whenever I use a php variable I usually concatonate it instead of embed it in the quotations.  So in the end I'd do something like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"movies.php?movie_id=" . $row['movie_id'] . "\"> Who Owns It? </a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Echo or URLs have nothing to do with your problem. It's [PHP strings syntax](http://php.net/types.string).

Answer (score 0):

The `$row['movie_id']` inside the double quoted string is not allowed (especially the single quotes). Either write it without `'` or use the curly braces syntax:

```
echo "<a href = \"movies.php/?movie_id='$row[movie_id]'\"> Who Owns It? </a> ";
echo "<a href = \"movies.php/?movie_id='{$row['movie_id']}'\"> Who Owns It? </a> ";
```

See [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way:

```
$movie_id = urlencode($row["movie_id"]);
echo '<a href="movies.php/?movie_id=', $movie_id, '"> Who Owns It? </a> ';
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a better(er) way:

```
$movie_id = urlencode($row["movie_id"]);
echo "<a href=\"movies.php?movie_id={$movie_id}\"> Who Owns It? </a> ";
```

Easier to read. Besides the single and double quote speed thing is not much of an issue any more.